# How can I use underscore in actions and controllers names

Tags: routes, zend-framework2

in the [Getting Started with Zend Framework 2 tuto](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/overview.html)

the requeste to add new album is  :  album.localhost/album/add

and I want it to appear like this :  album.localhost/my_album/my_add

is there a way to do this and how ?

thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When underscored words are used that are directly mapped to a controller/action the word will be converted to CamelCase variant with the first letter lowercased. So `my_album` becomes `myAlbum` and `my_add` becomes `myAdd`.

These changes are needed the get your example (http://album.localhost/my_album/my_add) working.

Your routing:

```
'route'    => '/my_album[/:action][/:id]',
```

You controller actions become camelCased:

```
public function myAddAction()
```